# Breastfeeding but periods have started after 2 months. What's going on inside the body?

Tags: health, breastfeeding, milk, c-section, menstruation

I'm curious to know I have periods just after a month of C-section. I'm fully breastfeeding my baby. Now he's 2.5 months old. Does periods happening decrease the production of breast-milk?

Comment: I will never disagree with a doctor call, but I don’t think this is asking medical advice - rather it’s asking what the relationship between periods and milk production which is a totally reasonable question for here!

Comment: While we can’t offer medical advice for individuals, questions about breastfeeding and it’s effect are perfectly acceptable here, as are answers that sticks to the same guidelines.

Answer (score 16):

First, menstruation doesn’t necessarily influence breast milk production. Some women notice a slight drop in supply in the second half of their cycle and an increased sensitivity or discomfort, others are not affected. These reports are mostly about women with already regular cycles and are usually not that much that baby’s needs aren’t met, so no need to worry here. Just keep on nursing, feeding on demand should mitigate any temporary reductions.

The phenomenon that very regular breastfeeding can suppress fertility and regular cycles after birth is called [lactational amenorrhea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactational_amenorrhea). The range of how long the absence of periods will last varies greatly. While for example [La Leche league states](https://www.llli.org/breastfeeding-info/fertility/) that *on average* regular periods resume after nine to eighteen months *for exclusively breastfeeding<sup>1</sup> mothers*, some women regain fertility just a couple of weeks after birth and others don’t get their periods until after the baby is weaned.

Frequency of breastfeeding - especially round the clock feeding - is an important factor and while breastfeeding and the resulting lactational amenorrhea can decrease the probability of becoming pregnant again, *please don’t consider it a reliable form of birth control* unless you are ok with a potential pregnancy. (We have a “but I’m breastfeeding” surprise baby in our friends’ circle.)

In short, bleeding can be a sign of hormonal changes and may indicate that a woman’s body is ready for another pregnancy, or it may a singular event without full onset of fertility. You may want to double-check with your healthcare provider if you suspect anything irregular.
———

<sup>1</sup> “Regular” means really regular as in every few hours, 24/7. The one night when baby sleeps “through” may be a blessing for the tired parents, but can already be enough to void the contraceptive effect.

Comment: I was thinking of answering this, but you did a great job already! +1. I was REALLY bummed when I started menstruating three weeks after my C-section. I was so looking forward to lactational amenorrhea, but nooooo..........!